# Click on input tag, not in form

Tags: web-scraping, mechanize, mechanize-ruby, mechanize-python

Im using `mechanize` to scrape a few pages. Pagination is implemented by a javascript post, and the pagination links are actually `input` buttons. These are not included in a form. Any idea how I could trigger a click on these?

Im still working on the script, and can use either `mechanize-ruby` or `mechanize-python`. A solution in either would help.

The html of the buttons is:

```
<input name="px" value="1" class="pSel" disabled="true\" type="button">
<input name="px" value="2" class="page_select" onclick="apply_pagination(this);" type="button">
<input name="px" value="3" class="page_select" onclick="apply_pagination(this);" type="button">
...
<input name="px" value="10" class="page_select" onclick="apply_pagination(this);" type="button">
```

Answer (score 1):

With mechanize-ruby you could find out the POST parameters by:

1. look at the `apply_pagination` javascript method and figure out what it posts back to the web server.
2. Click on one of the links on a browser and monitor the POST request using something like [HTTPFox] (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/).

With that you can easily replicate what the web server expects from the user agent and do something close to this;

```
next_page = agent.post("http://example.com/", { "foo" => "bar" })
```